# Number of tuples with certain types of elements

Tags: combinatorics

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a finite set and $n\in \mathbb N$. Moreover let $B:={b_1,\dots, b_l}\subset \mathcal{A}$ with $l\leq n$. I would like to compute the number of tuples $a\in\mathcal{A}^n$ s.t. the two conditions

- for every $b\in B$ there exists an $i=1,\dots,n$ with $a_i = b$
- for every $j=1,\dots, n$ it holds that $a_j\in B$

hold.

My approach: I think it should be
\begin{equation}
\binom{n}{l}\cdot l^{n-l},
\end{equation}
since we can firstly choose $l$ places out of $n$ to put each element of $B$. The remaining $w-l$ places can be filled with any element of $B$, hence the second factor.

I feel like I'm missing something... is this correct?

As a follow-up question: Is there a closed form for the sum

\begin{equation}
\sum_{l=1}^{n}\binom{n}{l}\cdot l^{n-l}?
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overcount in your calculation. You first pick every element of $B$, then pick other elements. If you swap any “first stage” element with a “second stage” element, it’s still the same tuple.

You want every $b_i$ be picked at least once. Hence the answer is $S(n,l)\cdot l!$ (see the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)).

Comment: I think I understand your reasoning with stirling numbers. However, why do you multiply with $l!$ ? Shouldn't $S(n,l)$ be enough, since every coordinate in $a$ gets assigned a number $1,...,l$?

Comment: @JosephExpo Groups in Stirling numbers are indistinguishable, but in your case $b_i$ are different, so we have to multiply by $l!$, where $l$ is the number of groups.

Comment: Thank you very much for the input!